# Does deleting a snapshot in Oracle VM also delete subsequent snapshots?

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine

Every time I take a snapshot in Oracle VM it hierarchically adds it below the previous.
I would like to clean up this long list and remove some of the snapshots snap.
But the documentation is not clear if that will affect subsequent snapshots or not.
The documentation says that snapshots are "differences" suggesting that deleting one in the middle might very well cause me to lose the following ones. But it's hard to believe that might be true and they don't state it in the docs. 
I certainly do not want to lose all subsequent snapshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that it should not affect the subsequent snapshots if you delete a prior snapshot, but why don't you test it real quick by taking two consecutive snapshots now, delete the first snapshot and then try restoring to the second snapshot, and if everything remains "hunky dory" you'd be good to go.

Comment: I did the test and it behaved well. Individual snapshots can be safely removed.